# New version of Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

If this is *off-topic* let me know and I will delete.

I want to buy a new Macbook Pro, but I don't know if it better to wait to a new version or to buy now the last version.

When Apple should announce the new Macbook Pro?

Comment: It is opinion but see http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/#Mac for some guesses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No-one really knows for certain when Apple are going to release new hardware except for Apple. So any answer is likely to be opinion-based which might get your question deleted.

That said, some sites online try to give an informed guess by analysing previous release schedules. For example, MacRumors who currently recommend against buying a Macbook Pro as they believe a new release is imminent.

http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/#Retina_MacBook_Pro

But like I said, this is just guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apple usualy releases new macbooks arround October-December. It depends which one you are imterested in the 13" or the 15" if you are looking at the 13" one there isnt actually that much to update for apple, it allready has the newer GpU and CPU, virtually the fastest PCI-e flash storage, only update could be CPU (Skylake) and possibly a new GPU, but the difference won't be dramatical at all. If you are looking at 15" model you could see significant update in GPU (small one in dedicated GPU and a bigger one in integrated GPU) and a bigger update in CPU since the current model still uses 2 generations old Haswell, it should be updated with skylake this year, but that is months and months away. If you are asking will there be any dramatical redesigns like there was eith the release of retina macbook pro, I dont think so, that should be atleast 1, 1,5 year from now.

Thats all the rummors there are out there for now.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same thing when Apple was bringing out its new Macbook.  Be aware that the refurbished MBPs will go on a very good sale in the 2 weeks before their new versions come out.  I ended up buying a 13" MBP with 16Gb ram /256 SSD for about $500 off.  Very similar to the refreshed models that came out, but a lot more affordable. :)